# java inheritance behaviour when super class has dao call?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a code as below:

```
Class A{

protected void method1(){

//i have  logic which will fetch the results from the database
}

}
```

and i have one more class which extends the class A:

```
Class B extends A{

    //some logic

    }
```

Now how many database calls are executed? one or two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do:

```
new B().method1()
```

`method1()` is called exactly once on behalf of `B` object. What the JVM is doing is it tries to find `B.method1()` first. If it was *overriden* in `B`, it would call it (and completely skip `A.method1()`). But since `B` is not overriding it, original `A.method1()` is called transparently.

If `B` would override `method1()` the only way to call original `A.method1()` would be to call `super.method1()` inside `B`.

Comment: And if it was overridden, it would just execute `B.method1()`, it wouldn't proceed to execute `A.method1()`. Unless of course you explicitly call `super.method1()` from `B.method1()` but that's a different story.

Comment: @biziclop: +1, thanks, I added some clarification in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

If you have written your logic in overridden method in `B` also in any case when your calling `methodm1` irrespective of classes only `one` call will go to database until you call method twice anyway.